# fputcsv more then one column (quotes)

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

When trying to generate a CSV I wanted to seperate data in multiple columns however I only see data in A1,A2,A3 columns not in b or C.

Any way how to fix this?

I want name X , age X and city X in three seperate columns

This is some example code :

```
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
// Disable caching
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
header("Expires: 0"); // Proxies

function outputCSV($data) {
    $output = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project_X/trunk/output/test.csv", 'w');
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row); // here you can change delimiter/enclosure
    }
    fclose($output);
}

outputCSV(array(
    array("name 1", "age 1", "city 1"),
    array("name 2", "age 2", "city 2"),
    array("name 3", "age 3", "city 3")
));
```

Edit : test function :

```
$output = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project_X/trunk/output/test.csv", 'w');
fputcsv($output, array("hallo;123;4"),";"); // here you can change delimiter/enclosure
fclose($output);
```

Outputs as file : "hallo;123;4" instead of hallo;123;4

Solved with this :

```
$array = array("hallo;123;4");
$array = str_replace('"', '', $array);
fputcsv($output, $array);
```

Comment: How are you looking at the generated file? You realise that MS Excel uses a locale-specific separator when reading a csv file, so sometimes you may need to use a `;`, somethimes a `,`, depending on the locale settings of the version of MS Excel being used to view the file that you produce

Comment: One solution to this is to "tell" MS Excel what separator is being used; make the first line of the file `sep=,`.... but this won't be good if the file is being used elsewhere by importer scripts

Comment: Thanks for the comments It was ; on the locale settings however its writing "test;1;2;3" instead of test;1;2;3 (without quotes) ? I re-edited the post and added a test function.

Comment: `fputcsv($output, array("hallo",123,4),";");` in your test, not `fputcsv($output, array("hallo;123;4"),";");`.... `array("hallo;123;4")` is creating an array with just one string element, so it will only write that as a single element for cell A1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting this issue because the array you are sending to the `fputcsv` function only has one element.

If you pass in the array as:
array("hallo", "123", "1"), then it will put each array element into the relevant columns.

the function `fputcsv` takes and array of individual elements, not a single string of data, and then the separator to use.  In your case a semi-colon.  The correct usage, using the array above, would be:
`fputcsv($output, array("hallo", "123", "1"), ';');`

That is: the file handler of the file, the array of individual element, not an array with a concatenated string, and then the separator to use in the file (a comma will be used if nothing is set here).